# LocationChangeStart event preventDefault not working

Tags: angularjs

I try to prevent navigate to a certain url with the following code

```
run(['$rootScope', '$location', function ($rootScope,$location) {
        $rootScope.$on('$locationChangeStart', function (event, next, current) {
            if (next) {
                if (isProhibetedUrl(next)) {
                    event.preventDefault();
                }
            }
        });
```

but it doesn't work and i enter a loop of 10 digests. I also tried $routeChangeStart with no success either.

Answer (score 0):

Here's how i use it with $routeStartChange. This is after you have defined the module.

```
app.run(['$rootScope', '$location',function ($rootScope, $location) {
    $rootScope.$on('$routeChangeStart', function (event) {
        if (!permitted) {    // your check
        event.preventDefault();
    }
});
```

Also be sure to have  'angular-route.js' included in your html, and dependency injected in module definition.

```
var app = angular.module('myapp', ['ngRoute',.....
```

Comment: Thank you. i have tried this implementation with no success. it stills navigates to the next page

Comment: Hoping you have  
    $routeProvider.when( ..   block all setup,

Answer (score 0):

It works perfectly fine. Please refer to the below plunkr. Try to apply the same to your code.

**Plunkr:** [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/tF2obFa4AKzAKxWNO5hY?p=preview)

So, just some question, is it entering the if condition if the condition is satisfied, can you do a console.log and check the conditions. If not then try to post a JSfiddle or Plunkr with just the issue to address, it will be easy to debug. Thanks.

**Code:**

```
    app.run(function($rootScope, $location) {
      //when the route is changed scroll to the proper element.
      $rootScope.$on("$locationChangeStart", function(event, next, current) {
        console.log(event);
        console.log(next);
        console.log(current);
        if(next.indexOf("two") !== -1){
          console.log("preventing default");
          event.preventDefault();
        }
      });
    });
```

**Explanation:**

The next route is checked for the keyword `two` if its present then, the event is stopped from propogating.  Please check the console if the if condition is entered.